# Platform specific settings in tox

Tags: python, tox

I would like to specify a few additional settings in my tox configuration, but only when I'm running on a certain platform.

For example, when running on windows I want an extra environment variable to be defined.  I would *like* to do something like this

```
[tox]
envlist = env1, env2, env_win32, env_arch

[testenv]
commands= 
    do stuff...

[testenv]
platform = arch
setenv = 
    NAME = VALUE

[testenv:env_win32]
plaform = win32
more = stuff

[testenv:env_arch]
platform = arch
more = different_stuff
```

but this doesn't work because of the duplicate testenv section.  I want the specified environment variable to apply to all environments (e.g. env1, env2, env_arch) but not on env_win32.

*Note:* The **specific** case that I'm dealing with is that on *nix platforms  we need to specify an extra environment variable for `install_command` only, so the command includes `/usr/bin/env NAME=VALUE` at the beginning.  Unfortunately, this doesn't exist on windows which causes it to fail.  I want to conditionally define the `install_command` differently depending on the platform to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

```
[tox]
envlist = env1, env2, env_win32, env_linux

[testenv]
install_command = pip install {opts} {packages}

[testenv-linux]
platform = linux
install_command = /usr/bin/env NAME=VALUE pip install {opts} {packages}

[testenv:env_win32]
plaform = win32
install_command = {[testenv]install_command}

[testenv:env_linux]
platform = linux
install_command = {[testenv-linux]install_command}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this solves my problem.  In my example, the commands are defined in the `[testenv]` section.  If I were to run `tox -e env1` on a linux machine it would run the commands in `[testenv]` without the additional environment variable configured.

Comment: Then you have to split your environments into linux- and w32-related and include proper `install_command` substitution in every environment. At least I don't see any way around that.